# Why/how do the elements of this array change between the console.log calls?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have an anuglarJS controller that calls an API via a service to return data. Ths issue is that sometimes, the data is not being updated in a directive that uses the data that is returned.

However, digging into this resulted in observing some very strange behavior. I added several console logs to debug what was happening, and discovered that the number of items in a property on the array is changing from one console call to the next.

The controller code is as follows:

```
 init(){
      this.ftService.getSitePromise(true).then((result: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<Site>) => {
      let ctrl = this;
      ctrl.isLoadingItems = true;
      ctrl.hideSplash = true;
      ctrl.siteReady = true;
      ctrl.curSite = result.data;
      ctrl.curSite.Items = [];
      console.log("end of header site call");
      ctrl.$timeout(function () {
         console.log(ctrl.curSite.Items);
         console.log("start get site items first call")
         ctrl.ftService.getSitePromise(false).then((result: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<Site>) => {
            console.log("return first call result.data.Items: " + result.data.Items.length);
            ctrl.curSite.Items = result.data.Items;
            ctrl.isLoadingItems = false;
            console.log("return first call ctrl.curSite.Items: " + ctrl.curSite.Items.length);
            console.log(ctrl);
            console.log(ctrl.curSite);
            console.log(ctrl.curSite.Items);
         });
      }, 200);   
   });
}
```

The console from this code executing, when the data isn't being shown as expected is as follows:

[image]

Any insight as to how this is occurring, and/or how I might correct it, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried changing the name of the second result from the promise?  You have two variables declared `result`.  That could be messing with it

Comment: If you hover over the `[i]` icon, you'll get some good advice. Namely, that when you expand the object, you're not necessarily seeing the object in the state it was in when you logged it.

Comment: @Fusion89k looks like it already minifies to a different variable, but I tried changing that and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: @Mike to which [i] icon are you referring? Nevermind, I just missed it.

Comment: you can't use `console.log` to troubleshoot async code.  `console.log` outputs the memory address of the object, not the contents of the object.  Therefore, it isn't showing the state of the object at the moment the call is made; rather it is showing the sate the object is in at the moment you interact with it in the console, and it can't show you the progression of a variable over time.

Comment: @MalibuCusser in light of the above, do you still have a logging issue when you stringify the object and log that?

Comment: @Fusion89k when stringified, all objects are the same. This voids my question and my confusion, and confirms that is was an issue with me trying to use the console for debugging. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I didn't read the comments before posting. I didn't see your problem was solved. Hopefully this may help someone else in the future??

> Why/how do the elements of this array change between the console.log calls?

Objects can change in `console.log` calls because the deeper nested properties are accessed lazily meaning that the console will only grab them when you click the little arrow to expand the object or if they are a shallow property.

You can change this behavior by cloning the object using [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Cloning_an_object) though you may need to clone the object deeply (which `Object.assign({}, myObj)` does not.

*The stackoverflow snippet console won't show the correct results.* Open your chrome dev tools to see the real result.

```js
// OPEN THE DEVELOPER TOOLS CONSOLE

let myObj = {
  shallowProp: 'some value',
  arr: ['initial value']
};

// notice that when this logs, it seems like the change to myObj happens before the log but it does not
console.log(
  'myObj initial log',
  myObj
);

// using `Object.assign` clones the object so that when expanded in the console, the value is the initial value
console.log(
  'myObj initial log with Object.assign',
  Object.assign({}, myObj)
);

// when the value is actually changed
myObj.arr = ['new value'];

// the final state
console.log('myObj after change', myObj);
```

Conclusion: try cloning your object before logging it the console.